# Process says invalid operation exception

Tags: c#, cmd, process

`Process` says `InvalidOperationException` but this command executes perfectly fine in the CMD. Some people say that there is a pipe in the argument so we should execute this with cmd.exe. that is not right. as have executed pipe command also.

I could not find why it's not running in the C#.

**Original command: "net user guest|findstr/C:active"**

**Expected Output: "Account active               Yes"**

here is my code.

```cs
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "net",
        Arguments = "user guest|findstr/C:active",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};

process.Start();
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried it like this "user guest|findstr /c:\"active\"", but still same result. and the same c# code works for all other commands.

Comment: It looks like your process has already exited by the time you took looked it up in the debugger.

Comment: I used this method
bool IsProcessExited = process.HasExited;
it's false, I think process never started.

Comment: @Nafis if you check the screenshot, the HasExited Flag is true

Comment: The pipe operator is not an argument. It's only meaningful to the command-line interpreter. So if you want to use `|` in your command, you have to make sure the _process_ executable is `cmd.exe`, and then pass the whole command line to that. See marked duplicate.

Comment: This is vbscript (`:` is the same as new line) showing how to programmatically access the info you want. `Set Col = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2").ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_UserAccount where name='Guest'"):For Each thing in Col:msgbox thing.disabled:Next`
  For Help `wmic path Win32_UserAccount get /?` and `wmic path Win32_UserAccount call /?`

Comment: when i added "/c" in argument its fixed. 
"/c net user guest|findstr/C:active"